# Map inside bootstrap sortable element - stop dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, sorting, bootstrap-4

I've got elements handled by Bootstrap sortable plugins (x_panels) and inside one of them, there is an element containing a map. Map is operated by dragging, as the sortable elements are. So when I try to drag the map, the start event of sortable is fired and I move the whole panel. My question is how to prevent sorting when dragging inside a map? I tried to make the panel container a handle, but it didn't work at all. I also tried to attach a handler to `mousedown` and `dragstart` events on the map and did `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` but it also didn't help.

Any ideas how to handle this?

container HTML:

```
<div id="widget-container" class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 widget-holder" id="x17">
<div class="x_panel">
    <div class="x_title">
        <h2><i class="fa fa-area-chart"></i> Title
            <small id="date-from-to">
            </small>
        </h2>
        <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox" style="min-width: auto">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-filter-{$data->id_widget_person}" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="x_content">
        <!-- This is the map container -->
        <div id="map-container" class="gmap"></div> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`#widget_container` contains all sortable elements.

Sortable handler:

```
$("#widget-container").sortable({
                            containerSelector: "#widget-container",
                            itemSelector: ".widget-holder",
            placeholder: "col-sm-3 widget-placeholder",
                            start: function(e, ui) {
                                ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height);
                                ui.placeholder.width(ui.item.width);
                            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                var data = $("#widget-container").sortable("toArray");
                                    console.log(data);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/url.php',
                    data: {
                        data: data
                    },
                    success: function(res) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }).disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

I already sorted it out by making `x_title` a handle, which has 100% width of panel, so I'm able to move the panel only by grabbing the upper portion of it, which is completely enough for me. If you still have an answer to this specific problem, feel free to post it.